# "Cannot find user in scope" SwiftUI Xcode error

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am creating an auth flow for my mobile app. I received an error: "Cannot find user in scope" on "self.userSession = user" & ".document(.user.uid)" I'm not sure how to resolve this error. Any help would be appreciated!

`

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    
    init() {
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        
        print("DEBUG: User session is \(self.userSession?.uid)")
    }
    
    func login(withEmail email: String, password: String) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to sign in with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            self.userSession = user
            print("DEBUG: Did log user in..")
        }
    }
    
    func register(withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to register with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            print("DEBUG: Registered user successfully.")
            print("DEBUG: User is \(self.userSession)")
            
            let data = ["email": email,
                        "fullname": fullname,
                        "uid": user.uid]
            
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
                .document(user.uid)
                .setData(data) { _ in
                    print("DEBUG: Did upload user data..")
                }
        }
    }
    
    func signOut() {
        // sets user session to nil so we show login view
        userSession = nil
        
        // signs user out on server
        try? Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
}
```

`

I have tried moving the declaration up on to the viewmodel but that caused another error: "cannot find result in scope".

Comment: you might need to replace `user` with `userSesseion`, because that is the var you are setting in `login()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use an auth state change listener to save user session as mentioned in the Firebase documentation. You should also not initialize the auth object every time in every function.

```
import FirebaseAuth

class AuthViewModel: Observable Object {
    private let auth: Auth = Auth.auth() // You can also use dependency injection

    @Published var userSession: User?

    private var authStatusHandler: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    func addAuthStatusListener() {
        if let handle = authStatusHandler {
            auth.removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
    
        authStatusHandler = auth.addStateDidChangeListener { _, user in
            self.userSession = user
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

In the register function, you try to access the "user" variable which is defined in the login function. This variable is out of the scope of the register function. You should use the userSession in the class for the register function.

```
func register(withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String) {
    ...
        
        let data = ["email": email,
                    "fullname": fullname,
                    "uid": userSession.uid] // <- Here
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
            .document(userSession.uid) // <- Here
            .setData(data) { _ in
                print("DEBUG: Did upload user data..")
            }
    ...
}
```